# Integrate Qt macros in flatbuffer cpp output

Tags: c++, qt, flatbuffers

I am using flatbuffers with C++ and it generates my classes, enums, etc. But I would like to use them in my QML GUI. Which means that I need some `QObject` and `QT_NAMESPACE`, `Q_ENUM` kind of macros.

How would you address such a problem? I am thinking of:

- Writing my own flatbuffer generator for my "own" language.
- Writing wrapper classes around the class and do some magic with QObject.
- I tried redefining the enum in another file, but Qt doesn't seem to pick that up.
- Parsing the code after flatc.exe is done and replacing specific keywords... :(

Example output of flatbuffer:

```
// automatically generated by the FlatBuffers compiler, do not modify


#ifndef FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_COMMON_OCS_N_COMMON_N_H_
#define FLATBUFFERS_GENERATED_COMMON_OCS_N_COMMON_N_H_

#include "flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h"

namespace ocs_n {
namespace common_n {

enum controlState_e {
  controlState_e_local = 0,
  controlState_e_released = 1,
  controlState_e_service = 2,
  controlState_e_operational = 3,
  controlState_e_MIN = controlState_e_local,
  controlState_e_MAX = controlState_e_operational
};

}
}
```

Comment: You could patch `flatc` to emit Qt-compatible enums (and even try to get it upstreamed)

Comment: You could certainly write your own generator to emit enums, but objects are a bit tougher, since FlatBuffers "objects" are nothing but pointers into a serialized buffer. Very likely this will not match with how QObject expects to operate.

Comment: I'm going to try and see if I can write another generator that writes `class ObjectWrapper : QObject, MyFlatBuffer_Builder` and see if I can get a direct mapping for the functions where it will just call the underlying flatbuffer functions. I will post an answer if I managed to do so.